# How do you create replies to answers?

Tags: bug, questions, feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I found an answer that really helped me. I tried to figure out how I could actually type in a reply (other than clicking on yes it helped me). I could edit the post, but there didn't seem to be any button I could click to add a comment to the answer.

Comment: You should only post a comment if you need clarification on the answer. If the answer is fine, then just accept it and/or upvote it. That's preferred over "Thanks" and other such comments.

Comment: Also, you will be able to upvote it once you have earned 15 reputation points on [SO].

Comment: In should be noted that comments are second class citizens and are not to be relied upon for any longer than the instant you post it.

Answer (score 7):

### Answer to your question

You need rep to be able to comment. As you use the site (by asking and answering questions), you gain "reputation" depending on the votes you recieve. At 15 rep [you can upvote a post](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), and you can [comment on all (non-locked) posts at 50](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

### Answer to your situation

SO is not a forum. The "answers" aren't "replies", they're *answers*. Similarly, comments aren't really for "thanks!"/etc, they're for asking for clarifications and making suggestions for improvement. Neither is editing for this purpose (as you have realized). Casting an up vote on the post is the best way to give thanks within the framework of this site.

Answer (score 4):

New users are not able to comment on other people's questions/answers until you have reached 50 rep.

You may want to check out the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) for when you can gain other privileges as well.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to express my appreciation. Not a big issue.

Comment: Appreciatian should be shown with an upvote (if available). Many "Thanks" messages just clutter up the site :)

Answer (score 3):

See the [privileges for comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You require minimum 50 reputation to comment everywhere.

From [FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/187824)

> ## Who can post comments?
>
> All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given
> to their own questions. Users with at least 50 reputation may comment
> on any post. (There is no reputation requirement to post comments on
> MSO.)